# How to draw an unrooted phylogenetic tree?

Tags: diagrams, trees

I have a problem! I want to draw an unrooted phylogenetic tree like this one:

[image]

(Image taken from [`commons.wikimedia`](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Unrooted_Phylogenetic_Tree_of_Helicase_Domain_in_c4orf21_Paralogs.jpg))

I've tried with the package `newicktree`, but without success! Anyone can help me please? If it is drawable without `newicktree` package it's ok too!
Thanks!

```
    \begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{newicktree}
        \setunitlength{4cm} \nobranchlengths \nodelabelformat{}
        \contemporarytips[30] \drawtree{ (((A,B)X,C)Y,D)Z;}
    \end{newicktree}    
    \caption{Example of phylogenetic tree.}
    \label{fig:phyltree}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Draw it??  I can't even say it!  Welcome to the site!  Perhaps showing us an actual minimum (non)working example of what you've tried would get us started.

Comment: I didn't find better words to say it :D I hope that the problem is equally clear :)

Comment: The problem is clear enough, but by not providing any code to get us started, you are asking the community of volunteers to sit down, learn the syntax of a potentially unknown package, and type it all in from scratch.  You are more likely to get assistance if you provide some code to set us in the right direction.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is easier to help you if you add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you - and much more likely that they will!

Comment: You are right, I'm new in the community sorry! :) I've uploaded the code (how can I formatted the code well as you did a minute ago?)

Comment: If you highlight the code and click the `{}` box above the edit box, it will format it.  The same can be achieved if you indent each line 4 spaces.  For inline code, just delimit it with grave accents like this: `piece of code` inline.

Comment: Please give us a hint: where is `newicktree`? It does not seem to be on CTAN.

Comment: `newicktree` can be found here [The newicktree package](http://cbr.jic.ac.uk/dicks/software/newicktree/). I've downloaded the  `.sty` file from the homepage and also the documentation.

Comment: I can draw something which looks a little like the 2 pieces. (It is structurally the same although the angles are different.) But how do you join them? (Can you join them?)

Comment: It is not mandatory to use the `newicktree` package.. if the result is reached using another type of package is good too!

Comment: You are probably better off thinking of it as a graph since it is not really a tree. Take a look at the graph drawing facilities of TikZ if LuaLaTeX is an option.

Comment: It is not so simple like it seems..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this helps a little:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{newicktree}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \begin{newicktree}
    \setunitlength{4cm} \nobranchlengths \nodelabelformat{}
    \contemporarytips[30] \drawtree{ (((A,B)X,C)Y,D)Z;}
  \end{newicktree}
  \caption{Example of phylogenetic tree.}
  \label{fig:phyltree}
\end{figure}
\begin{newicktree}
  \straightbranches\nobranchlengths\nonodemarkers
  \lefttree\setunitlength{2mm}
  \drawtree{(((thing 1:5, thing 10:5):3, thing 9:6):4, thing 2:7):8, ((thing 7:3, thing 8:3):10, thing 3:10):5,
  (thing 6:20, (thing 4:1, thing 5:2):10):1;}
\end{newicktree}

\end{document}
```

[image: tree]

Comment: Now the problem is to connect the tree with the right part. However, this is very helpful (it is a type of unrooted phylogenetic tree) :)